# How to xpath for element with two possible last element?

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

I have complex xpath selector. I want to make it generic, so it could point to input and textarea.

example xpath's

```
//someelement//input

//someelement//textarea
```

how to merge those two into single xpath?

Comment: Means you want to select either an `input` or `textarea` as long as it's a descendant of `someelement`?

Comment: What exactly would you want to exclude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an union:

```
 //someelement//input  | //someelement//textarea
```

Or in XPath  2:

```
//someelement//(input, textarea)
```